Как подключить InputStream к клавиатуре?
Нужен InputStream напрямую в клавиатуру
такой код не считывает клавиатуру, если фокус на окне, только если я напишу в консоль.
При этом он требует кнопки enter и даёт разный результат в зависимости от текущего языка. А клавиатура по идее должна  давать 1 байт нажатой кнопки.
То есть System.in подключён к консоли.
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setBounds(200,200,800,600);
frame.setVisible(true);

InputStream in = System.in;
System.out.println("Читаю:");
int key = in.read();        
System.out.println(key+" = "+ (char)key);

Как подключить InputStream к клавиатуре?

Погугли про addKeyListener. Через InputStream клавиатуру не прочитать.

System.in представляет системный поток ввода и он будет выполнять чтение из консоли, в которой запускается java-приложение java -jar my.jar.  В представленном коде из консоли будет запускаться другое графическое окно JFrame, которое не содержит никаких полей ввода.   Теоретически оно может обрабатывать события клавиатуры, если в коде будет создан и правильно зарегистрирован соответствующий KeyListener, но эти события никак не будут связаны с системным потоком ввода.
